# move arrow image infornt of line in textarea with Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, textarea

I want to move arrow image in textarea on mouse click and key up and down like text editors.

Pls give me ur suggestions

Regards,
Shivang

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this with a combination of a click handler and a skin that draws the arrow for the cursor.

Comment: Hi,
Pls can u give more detail or any example on this.
Thanks for reply.